# Average of calculated text fields

Tags: excel, average, duration

I am trying to calculate the average duration of an automated job.  This is a sample of the data I am using:

```
START_TIME     END_TIME         TOTAL_TIME  Minutes Hrs:Mins
1/1/16 6:58 AM  1/1/16 10:53 AM 11132769    235     3:55
1/2/16 6:54 AM  1/2/16 2:28 PM  16322534    454     7:34
1/3/16 6:44 AM  1/3/16 1:24 PM  14714442    400     6:40
1/4/16 6:29 AM  1/4/16 11:48 AM 12390047    319     5:18
1/5/16 6:40 AM  1/5/16 12:14 PM 11290069    334     5:34
1/6/16 9:13 AM  1/6/16 8:00 PM  15891032    647     10:47
```

I used the following formula to derive the "Hrs:Mins" field: {=TEXT(C2-B2,"H:MM")}.  What I want is the average Hrs:Mins.  No matter what I've tried, and I've reviewed MANY questions/responses, I get the ubiquitous #DIV/0! error. 
Can someone please help?

FYI, the "START_TIME", "END_TIME", "TOTAL_TIME" and "Minutes" columns/values were copied and pasted from an mssql query; I added the "Hrs:Mins" field to more easily show in hours and minutes the lengths of the jobs.

Thanks in advance!
Rob

Comment: With the Text formula you are making the values into text, and text cannot be used in mathematical formulas.  So change the text formula to only `=C2-B2` then use a custom number format either through cell format or the ribbon.  The custom format is "h:mm".  Then the cell is a number that looks like a time.  Then you can use the normal average function.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, new to posting on Stackoverflow; still learning how to format copied data.

Comment: you can also just average the minutes columns, then convert the average to `H:MM` format. Something like `=TEXT(AVERAGE(D2:D7)),"H:MM")`

Comment: Thanks, Scott and Scott, problem solved!